# Example of "no analytical solution"

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Is there a good test for no analytical solution? How can I learn the difference between equations that have an analytical solution and the ones that need numerical methods ("unsolvables" in analysis)?

Comment: cos (x) =x.  it depends what you mean by anylitical solution.

Comment: @shaihorowitz Analytical solution as an exact solution, I suppose. If I can calculate an exact solution with an analytic proof, that would I say is an analytical solution compared to measurements and approximations.

Comment: If it is defined then that definition is the analytical solution.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver  this debatebly has no analytical solutions for large vales. this has to do with godel's thereom.

Comment: @shaihorowitz Interesting...